# Hide Category in Highchart if all data is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

This is a sample fiddle : [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/htXNB/54/)

**Code**

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -100,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 20,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [null, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [null, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [null, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

What I want is if all series data for the Apple category is null then the chart should not display Apple at all.

This is a multi series data, where as I want a solution for single series data or multi series data or even for any other type of chart like pie chart etc.

Thanks,

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8c3o4/ apple category is not displayed but still you have to update the series containing data with not null values( each array will now contains 4 element instead of 5 elements)

Comment: hi, if you can see it created i think another value over there.

My actual problem is i'm showing a simple bar chart for all 12 months but lets say data for jan feb is null so i dont want to show jan feb in the chart instead of not showing the bar @Deep3015

Comment: then in that case it can be done from server side manipulation, where you can set categories as well as data accordingly

Comment: can you elaborate a bit or any supporting example? @Deep3015

Comment: check this https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database

Comment: thanks but it didnt helped :) @Deep3015

Comment: Process the data before you render the chart. What you need is an algorithm for filtering the data - is not strictly related to the chart. A general solution depends on how your data is structured - for your fiddle, you can filter data like this http://jsfiddle.net/8n5vsp1r/

Comment: You can look at these two Highcharts forum topics: https://forum.highcharts.com/post122656.html#p122656
https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16169